# Removing nested for loops as additional functions in python

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm looking to convert some of my nested for loops into separate functions to improve readability and usability. However I am running into the following error:

```
TypeError: condition should be string or Column
```

Here is the code I started with:

```
def combine_filter(base_filter, new_filter, operation='or'):
    if base_filter is None:
        return new_filter
    if operation == 'or':
        return (base_filter) | (new_filter)
    else:
        return (base_filter) & (new_filter)

simple_match_terms = {
    'exact': ['FIRST', 'LAST', 'NAME'],
    'contains': ['NOMBRE', 'APELLIDO', 'FNAME', 'LNAME'],
    'can_not_contain': []
}
for name_type in ['FIRST', 'LAST', 'FULL', 'CONTACT', 'YOUR']:
    for connector in [' ', '', '_', '-']:
        simple_match_terms['contains'].append(f'{name_type}{connector}NAME')
        
simple_filter = None
for match_type, match_terms in simple_match_terms.items():
    new_simple_filter = None
    for ff_column in ['id', 'label', 'name']:
        for match_term in match_terms:
            if match_type == 'exact':
                new_simple_filter = combine_filter(new_simple_filter, 
                                                   (col(ff_column) == match_term),
                                                   operation='or')
            elif match_type == 'contains':
                new_simple_filter = combine_filter(new_simple_filter, 
                                                   (col(ff_column).contains(match_term)),
                                                   operation='or')
            elif match_type == 'can_not_contain':
                new_simple_filter = combine_filter(new_simple_filter, 
                                                   (~col(ff_column).contains(match_term)),
                                                   operation='or')
        if new_simple_filter is not None:
            if match_type == 'can_not_contain':
                simple_filter = combine_filter(simple_filter, new_simple_filter, operation='and')
            else:
                simple_filter = combine_filter(simple_filter, new_simple_filter)

df = df.filter(simple_filter)
```

df is a dataframe with the following columns:
'token', 'optionlabel', 'value', 'label', 'id', 'name', 'checked','type', 'email', 'phone'

Here is the code that is now breaking:

```
def combine_filter(base_filter, new_filter, operation='or'):
    if base_filter is None:
        return new_filter
    if operation == 'or':
        return (base_filter) | (new_filter)
    else:
        return (base_filter) & (new_filter)
        
def _match_results(match_type, match_terms, ff_column):
    simple_filter = None
    new_simple_filter = None
    for match_term in match_terms:
        if match_type == 'exact':
            new_simple_filter = combine_filter(new_simple_filter, 
                                               (col(ff_column) == match_term),
                                               operation='or')
        elif match_type == 'contains':
            new_simple_filter = combine_filter(new_simple_filter, 
                                               (col(ff_column).contains(match_term)),
                                               operation='or')
        elif match_type == 'can_not_contain':
            new_simple_filter = combine_filter(new_simple_filter, 
                                               (~col(ff_column).contains(match_term)),
                                               operation='or')
        if new_simple_filter is not None:
            if match_type == 'can_not_contain':
                simple_filter = combine_filter(simple_filter, new_simple_filter, operation='and')
            else:
                simple_filter = combine_filter(simple_filter, new_simple_filter)
    return simple_filter

simple_match_terms = {
    'exact': ['FIRST', 'LAST', 'NAME'],
    'contains': ['NOMBRE', 'APELLIDO', 'FNAME', 'LNAME'],
    'can_not_contain': []
}
for name_type in ['FIRST', 'LAST', 'FULL', 'CONTACT', 'YOUR']:
    for connector in [' ', '', '_', '-']:
        simple_match_terms['contains'].append(f'{name_type}{connector}NAME')

for match_type, match_terms in simple_match_terms.items():
    for ff_column in ['id', 'label', 'name']:
        _match_results(match_type, match_terms, ff_column)

df = df.filter(simple_filter)
```

Just no idea what this error means or why it would come up. Am definitely open to better ways of rewriting this entirely to be more pep compliant, my python knowledge is very informal and on the job learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference here is in `simple_filter`.  In your original code, you build up `simple_filter` as a combination of the four column filters.  In your second code, you create `simple_filter` anew in each call, and although you return it, you then throw it away.  I believe the changes you need are small:

```
def _match_results(match_type, match_terms, ff_column, simple_filter):
    new_simple_filter - None
    for match_term in match_terms:
        ... etc, the rest is the same ...
```

Then, at the very end:

```
simnple_filter = []
for match_type, match_terms in simple_match_terms.items():
    for ff_column in ['id', 'label', 'name']:
        simple_filter = _match_results(match_type, match_terms, ff_column, simple_filter)

df = df.filter(simple_filter)
```